# PDO OCI fetch blob failed with ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I just installed PDO-OCI 1.0 on my CentOS 6.4 64-bit server, but I have a problem when trying to fetch BLOB columns that are NULL, PDO throws an exception with "ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL".

I couldn't find much on this topic on the web. There seems to be a bug report at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36974 but it says the problem is "Fixed in PHP 5.2.1". However, I'm using 5.3.3. and experience the same problem.

Does someone have an idea on how I could fix that/workaround maybe? Or do I have to file a new bug report and wait forever for it to be looked at?

Comment: Did you try to add a try instance as a workaround?

Comment: Same bug... running PHP 5.5.9 with PDO-OCI... fetching NClob throws this error as well :-( Any clue or workaround?